# Why doesn't my Raspberry Pi's IP address show up on my D-LINK router under LAN?

Tags: ssh, router

I have a Raspberry Pi B R3, and I want to configure it to be a server. I am planning on plugging it directly to my router and then using SSH to control it. I have turned on SSH, moved my RPi to the router to try it, plugged it in, and then logged into the settings page of my router. However, it doesn't show up under "LAN COMPUTERS." Is this where it's supposed to show up? There's another place for WLAN connections, but I'm using ethernet.

I have also tried to set a static IP address on the Pi, but I can't tell if it's working because it won't open in Putty, and there is no monitor nearby. The only thing that I can connect my RPi to is my 50' TV about 60 feet away from my router, so moving it isn't an option, and I don't have a ethernet cable that long.. It will be easy to use with SSH once I get it running, but I can't seem to get it going. **Is this a problem with my router or with my RPi configuration?**

I would've put this question under RPI.SE, but I think that it's more my router's problem than my Pi's.

My router is a D-Link DIR-600 Hardware Revision A1 with the latest firmware (1.01NA it says).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual for your router, you can access a list of all of the connected devices, LAN or otherwise, at Setup -> LAN Setup. You can also reserve an IP Address for your Raspberry Pi here too, if your Pi is using DHCP, which I assume it is.

By the way, good luck. I did the same thing as you with my Raspberry Pi.

Here's where I found the manual: http://www.dlink.com/-/media/Consumer_Products/DIR/DIR%20600/Manual/DIR_600_B_2_Manual_EN_UK.pdf#page=31

Comment: Wow. Been there 15 times but never noticed that. Thanks for the help! It worked perfectly.